# How to improve and streamline the process of riverpod state management

Tags: flutter, riverpod, state-management

I'm quite new to state management using riverpod and this is my repo fro the project https://github.com/quezera97/contact_reader

at my_contact.dart i run initData() to get from DB (sqlite), if empty i get from provider (i don't know if this code is the best or need improvement

```
class MyContact extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyContact({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyContact> createState() => _MyContactState();
}

class _MyContactState extends ConsumerState<MyContact> {
  late List<ContactModel> allContactDB = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initData();
  }

  Future<void> initData() async {
    try {
      List<ContactModel> allContact = await DatabaseHelper.getAllContact() ?? [];

      if(allContact.isEmpty){
        allContact = await ref.read(getAllContactProvider.future);
      }

      ref.read(contactProvider.notifier).setContactsProvider(allContact);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching data: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    allContactDB = ref.watch(contactProvider);
```

and I use this code below to display using list tile

```
if (allContactDB.isNotEmpty) ...[
    ListView.builder(
    itemCount: allContactDB.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      ContactModel contact = allContactDB[index];
     String avatar = contact.avatar ?? '';
```

SO FROM = `await ref.read(getAllContactProvider.future);`

call this

```
final contactService = ContactService();

final getAllContactProvider = FutureProvider<List<ContactModel>>((ref) async {
  try {
    List<ContactModel> users = await contactService.getAllUsers();

    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    print('Error fetching users: $error');
    return [];
  }
});
```

and from `List<ContactModel> users = await contactService.getAllUsers();`

I CALL to get from api url & local contact (flutter_contact)

```
class ContactService {
  String allUserUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

  Future<List<ContactModel>> getAllUsers() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(allUserUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];

      List<ContactModel> allContact = [];
      List<ContactModel> contactList = result.map((contactJson) => ContactModel.fromJson(contactJson)).toList();
      if(contactList.isNotEmpty || contactList != []){
        allContact.addAll(contactList);
      }

      List<Contact> localContacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts();
      List<ContactModel> contactModels = localContacts.map((contact) => ContactModel.fromContact(contact)).toList();
      if(localContacts.isNotEmpty || localContacts != []){
        allContact.addAll(contactModels);
      }

      for (var contact in allContact) {
        await DatabaseHelper.addContact(contact);
      }

      return allContact;
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the notifier provider from `ref.read(contactProvider.notifier).setContactsProvider(allContact);`

```
final contactProvider = StateNotifierProvider<ContactProvider, List<ContactModel>>(
  (ref) => ContactProvider(),
);

class ContactProvider extends StateNotifier<List<ContactModel>> {
  ContactProvider() : super([]);

  void setContactsProvider(List<ContactModel> contacts) {
    state = contacts;
  }

  void updateContactProvider(ContactModel updatedContact) {
    state = state.map((contact) =>
      contact.id == updatedContact.id ? updatedContact : contact
    ).toList();
  }

  void addContactsProvider(ContactModel contact) {
    state = [...state, contact];
  }

  void clearContactsProvider() {
    state = [];
  }

  void removeContactsProvider(int? contactId) {
    state = state.where((contact) => contact.id != contactId).toList();
  }
}
```

I get what I need in CRUD and whats not, but it seems so weird and I think it need improvement in using riverpod, i did watch some videos and read, but quite not understand. So i need your suggestion in streamlining my code in using riverpod